# Forecasting an Index using google Trend Data in r

Tags: regression, arima

I am referring to my question [Forecasting an index with google in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445992/forecasting-an-index-with-google-in-r/446021?noredirect=1#comment830047_446021) .

I am aiming to forecast an Index (dependent variable) by using Google Trend Data (independent variable). I prefer using R. I really liked  "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" by Rob Hyndman where different forecasting methods are explained step by step. I got the advice that an ARIMAX model would be helpful but I wasn't able to build a fitting model.

My data look like followed:

```
  frequency(independent variable):
3
2
5
3
3
4
6
5
8
6
5
4
4
7
7
5
9
8
9
8
9
11
11
11
15
16
19
12
26
30
29
24
32
36
38
28
39
45
48
39
52
55
58
44
65
68
69
59
70
71
75
58
77
79
77
71
90
88
94
75
98
90

index(dependent variable:
83.9
82.8
81.9
80.6
84.2
82.7
84.4
82
83.2
83.5
82.3
83
80
81.7
81.6
81.6
82.8
83.1
81.6
81.8
81.8
83.1
82.9
84.2
83
84.3
84.3
83.8
86
87.1
86.7
87.3
87.9
89.1
90.4
91.6
91.3
93.1
92.9
93
93.8
95.7
96.2
96.2
97.8
99.9
100.4
101.8
103.9
106.9
108.8
110.4
110.9
113.1
115
117.3
118.3
120.6
123.1
124.6
124.4
126.9
```

Thank you for every type of help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a Standard Power equation plus offset, "index = a * pow(frequency, b) + Offset", fits the data OK with parameters a = 1.4673699132616930E-02, b = 1.7539637597199835E+00, and Offset = 8.2138064560445230E+01 yielding R-squared = 0.939 and RMSE = 3.345. My thought is that such a simple equation should extrapolate well.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain how you find that equation? (maybe the R code, if you did it with R)

Comment: I used the "function finder" on my zunzun.com open source curve fitting web site, looking for equations with three or less parameters. This equation seemed like a good candidate.